# How to get the name of person by passing city property from array of JS object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of objects

```
const arrofobj = [
{city:"paris", name: "chris"},
{city:"berlin", name: "john"},
{city:"moscow", name: "jev"}
];
```

I want to write a function when I pass paris, I want to get back chris, how to achieve this?

Here is what I have tried

```
const arrofobj = [
{city:"paris", name: "chris"},
{city:"berlin", name: "john"},
{city:"moscow", name: "jev"}
];

function fetchname(cityname) {
  arrofobj.forEach((val)=>{if(Object.keys(val) == "city") {if (val.city == cityname) console.log(val.name)}})//nothing is printed
}

fetchname("paris");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will help you
Hvae you any question in this code. Comment below

```
    const arrofobj = [
  {city:"paris", name: "chris"},
  {city:"berlin", name: "john"},
  {city:"moscow", name: "jev"}
 ];

function fetchname(cityname) {
  const findValue = arrofobj.find((value)=>value.city==cityname)
    console.log(findValue)
    return findValue.name ?? ""
}

 fetchname("paris");
```

Answer (score 1):

You able to use filter

```js
const arrofobj = [
  {city:"paris", name: "chris"},
  {city:"berlin", name: "john"},
  {city:"moscow", name: "jev"}
];

console.log(arrofobj.filter((arro) =>arro.city == 'paris')[0].name);
```

Answer (score 1):

you must use filter method as follow:

```js
const arrofobj = [
    {city:"paris", name: "chris"},
    {city:"berlin", name: "john"},
    {city:"moscow", name: "jev"}
    ];
    
    function getByCity(city) {            
        var result = arrofobj.filter(obj => {
            return obj.city === city
        })
        return result;
    }

    console.log(getByCity('paris')[0].name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I made one little change to your code that you provided and it works fine now

```
const arrofobj = [
{city:"paris", name: "chris"},
{city:"berlin", name: "john"},
{city:"moscow", name: "jev"}
];

function fetchname(cityname) {
  arrofobj.forEach((val)=>{if(Object.keys(val)[0] == "city") {if (val.city 
== cityname) console.log(val.name)}})//works fine now
}

fetchname("paris");
```

Object.keys returns an array of keys of the object city key is at first index hence [0] since you used object.keys and were comparing it without [0] it was comparing the array object hence getting false and not printing